# UK family visa: can I bring my grandchild to UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I want to bring my grandson (US citizen, 11 years old) to UK to go to a private school. Unfortunately the schools that offer to sponsor child students are prohibitively expensive, so I'm considering alternatives, and it seems a family visa might be a possibility; at least for parents living in UK. Is this a possible route in our case?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [Expatriates.SE], but in short the answer is no: "grandchild" is not on the [list of family relationships](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa).  Depending on your circumstances, though, it's possible that your grandson [is a British citizen or eligible to register for British citizenship](https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-british-parent/born-on-or-after-1-july-2006).